# Make an hyperref link to current chapter/section

Tags: hyperref

I would like a way to make an hyperref link to the beginning of the current section or chapter, that has the same effect of using `\label{section}` and `\ref{section}` with `hyperref` on, but without having to use `\label`.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[linktoc=all,hidelinks,bookmarksnumbered,pagebackref,xetex]{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[3-5]

\section{Section 2}
\lipsum[6]
\textbf{Link to current section.}\\
\textbf{Link to current chapter.}\\
\lipsum[6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the `current` section and what is wrong with `\label`?

Comment: The "current" section is the section where the link is. Since I would use this function quite a lot, it would be nicer not to have to label them each time.

Comment: Anyway, this means auto-labelling somewhat. How do you want to refer to the current section. The current section 'moves' through the document when being viewed.

Comment: See the edited question if it is clearer.

Comment: The table of contents already has links to all the chapters etc.  The names can be found in the aux file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[linktoc=all,hidelinks,bookmarksnumbered,pagebackref,xetex]{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}\hypertarget{chapter::\theHchapter}{}%
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[3-5]

\section{Section 2}\hypertarget{section::\theHsection}{}%
\lipsum[6]
\hyperlink{section::\theHsection}{\textcolor{blue}{Link to current section.}}
\hyperlink{chapter::\theHchapter}{\textcolor{blue}{Link to current chapter.}}
\lipsum[6]



\chapter{Chapter 1}\hypertarget{chapter::\theHchapter}{}%
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[3-5]

\section{Section 2}\hypertarget{section::\theHsection}{}%
\lipsum[6]
\hyperlink{section::\theHsection}{\textcolor{blue}{Link to current section.}}
\hyperlink{chapter::\theHchapter}{\textcolor{blue}{Link to current chapter.}}
\lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't need to add hypertargets.  They are already there.  The format is "chapter.\arabic{chapter}" and "section.\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}" not "chapter.\thechapter".

Comment: Perfect. `\hyperlink{section.\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}{Link to current section.}` does exactly what I want. Many thanks to you two.

Comment: Actually, \theHsection and \theHchapter are formatted that way too.

Comment: Is it possible to refer to `\label`s I placed? I've tried to `\hyperlink{\ref{chap:last}}{Last}`, but it fails: `Use of \hyper@link@ doesn't match its definition.`