# Hypertarget pointing at \thefigure

Tags: hyperref

Hopefully the last question I would ask about the extended figure caption macro. In the last version [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279516/automatically-protect-new-paragraph-in-extended-figure-caption), `hyperref` do not affect `\addefcline` or `\efcline`, leaving me the task of having to define an hypertarget on the figure every time I use the `\extcaption` function.

In short, how could I make an hypertarget that point at `\thefigure` to make the process automatic ? Also, is there some sort of `ifhyperref` package (to check whether hyperref is loaded) ?

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

% Redefinition of \addcontentsline
\long\def\addefcline#1#2#3{%
  \addtocontents{#1}{\efcline{#2}{#3}{\thepage}}}

% Redefinition of \contentsline
\makeatletter
\long\def\efcline#1{\csname l@#1\endcsname}
\makeatother

% Extended figure caption
\newcommand{\extcaption}[1]{% Write to .efc file
  \addefcline{efc}{extfig}{{%
    \bfseries \protect\hyperlink{fig:\thefigure}{Figure \thefigure, page~\thepage:}} %
    \unexpanded{\unexpanded{#1}}%
  }%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printextcaptions}{\@starttoc{efc}}% Read .efc file
\newcommand{\l@extfig}[2]{\noindent #1 \vspace{\parskip} \par}% How each .efc entry is handled
\makeatother

\usepackage[linktoc=all]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image-a.pdf}
\caption{Picture of a big A}\hypertarget{fig:\thefigure}{}
\extcaption{\lipsum[1-2]}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image-b.pdf}
\caption{Picture of a big B}\hypertarget{fig:\thefigure}{}
\extcaption{The reasons why B is awful
\begin{itemize}
\item "B" like Bad
\item "B" like Banana
\end{itemize}
}
\end{figure}

\section{Extended figure captions}
\printextcaptions
\end{document}
```

Comment: \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{ true }{ false } should do.  As for \hypertarget, you might look at the hycap package.

Comment: `\AtBeginDocument\\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{}{}` does the trick indeed. However, hypcap requires you to either set the anchor manually, or automatically but making sure all figures have captions ... isn't there a way to link aimply to \figure ? I asked a similar question previously to link at a \thesection http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270141/make-an-hyperref-link-to-current-chapter-section

Comment: I suspect you don't NEED a caption with hycap, you just need \stepcounter{figure}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution using the `hyperref`'s `\@currentHref` variable.This gives the final code:

```
% Redefinition of \addcontentsline
\long\def\addefcline#1#2#3{%
  \addtocontents{#1}{\efcline{#2}{#3}{\thepage}}}
% Redefinition of \contentsline
\makeatletter
\long\def\efcline#1{\csname l@#1\endcsname}
% Extended figure caption
\AtBeginDocument{\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{ % If hyperref loaded
\newcommand{\extcaption}[1]{% Write to .efc file
  \addefcline{efc}{extfig}{{%
    \bfseries \protect\hyperlink{\@currentHref}{Figure \thefigure, page~\thepage:}} %
    \unexpanded{\unexpanded{#1}}}}}{% If hyperref not loaded
\newcommand{\extcaption}[1]{% Write to .efc file
  \addefcline{efc}{extfig}{{%
    \bfseries Figure \thefigure, page~\thepage:} %
    \unexpanded{\unexpanded{#1}}%
  }}}}
% Read .efc file
\newcommand{\printextcaptions}{\@starttoc{efc}}
\newcommand{\l@extfig}[2]{\noindent #1 \vspace{\parskip} \par}% How each .efc entry is handled
\makeatother
```

To recap, an extended Figure caption is added inside the figure float like

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image-a.pdf}
\caption{Picture of a big A}
\extcaption{\lipsum[1-2]}
\end{figure}
```

, generating an `.efc` file containing all the content of `\extcaption{}`, which are printed by

```
\printextcaptions
```